# Using combine() & aperm() function for training -- issue with first argument, must be an array

Tags: r

i'm trying to create a training set by combining two lists and making it into an array, then combing two arrays using aperm but im getting an error stating:

```
Error in aperm.default(combine(train_Set), c(1, 2)) : invalid first argument, must be an array
```

Here is what the code looks like below:

```
train_Set <- c(Smiling[1:50], Non_smiling[1:50])
train<-aperm(combine(train_Set), c(1,2))
```

I'm not sure if this is done correctly, can anyone give me input as to why im getting this error and how I can correct this?

Comment: `combine(train_Set), c(1,2)` is a vector.  `aperm` requires data formatted as an array.

Comment: If you want a simple 2 column matrix then `train <- matrix(Smiling, Not_smiling)`